# Adding functionality before calling constructor in extra constructor

Tags: scala

Is it possible to add functionality before calling constructor in extra constructor in scala ?

Lets say, I have class User, and want to get one string - and to split it into attributes - to send them to the constructor:

```
class User(val name: String, val age: Int){
    def this(line: String) = {
       val attrs = line.split(",") //This line is leading an error - what can I do instead
       this(attrs(0), attrs(1).toInt)
    }
}
```

So I know I'm not able to add a line before sending to this, because all constructors need to call another constructor as the first statement of the constructor.

Then what can I do instead?

Edit:

I have a long list of attributes, so I don't want to repeat `line.split(",")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a place where companion object and `apply()` method come nicely into play:

```
object User {
  def apply(line: String): User = {
    val attrs = line.split(",")
    new User(attrs(0), attrs(1).toInt)
  }
}

class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

Then you just create your object the following way:

```
val u1 = User("Zorro,33")
```

Also since you're exposing `name` and `age` anyway, you might consider using case class instead of standard class and have consistent way of constructing `User` objects (without `new` keyword):

```
object User {
  def apply(line: String): User = {
    val attrs = line.split(",")
    new User(attrs(0), attrs(1).toInt)
  }
}

case class User(name: String, age: Int)

val u1 = User("Zorro,33")

val u2 = User("Zorro", "33")
```

Comment: you don't need to make it case class solely for a purpose of hiding new: use private for a constructor and yet another apply method in companion

Answer (score 2):

Ugly, but working solution#1:

```
class User(val name: String, val age: Int){
    def this(line: String) = {
       this(line.split(",")(0), line.split(",")(1).toInt)
    }
}
```

Ugly, but working solution#2:

```
class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
object User {
  def fromString(line: String) = {
     val attrs = line.split(",")
     new User(attrs(0), attrs(1).toInt)
  }
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
val johny = User.fromString("johny,35")
```

You could use `apply` in place of `fromString`, but this will lead to a confusion (in one case you have to use `new`, in the other you have to drop it) so I prefer to use different name

Comment: I think I will use your second solution, if there is not a better one... I see scala is a bit disappointing

Comment: You can make second solution prettier with patmat: `line.split('.') match { case Array(a, b) => new User(a, b.toInt) }`

Comment: @AlexIv I prefer `val Array(a, b) = line.split(","); new User(a, b.toInt)` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another ugly solution:

```
class User(line: String) {
  def this(name: String, age: Int) = this(s"$name,$age")

  val (name, age) = {
    val Array(nameStr,ageStr) = line.split(",")
    (nameStr,ageStr.toInt)
  }
}
```

But using a method of the companion object is probably better.